# How to implement Tabs UI in android

Tags: android

I have existed code for two activities(ActivityA and ActivityB).

Now I need to have a another activity, which will act as my first and only screen of my application. This activity will be having two tabs on its header part and I need to display each of my Activity when user press on each tab.

I have done some search on this and found `TabAcivity` will be suitable choice, but it is deprecated now. 
I saw many posts which are suggesting `Fragments`. But I dont want to change my existing code. Can any one suggest me easy method to incorporate this.

Comment: Used `FragmenTabHost` instead of simple `TabHost` and also extends `FragmentActivity` instead of simple `Activity` and go to [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html)

Comment: You could also use an action bar with navigation tabs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

Answer (score 0):

you can use Android Tab Layout with Swipeable Views

here i give Link in this link step by step information given. so i think you can get batter idea from that.

[Tab Layout with Swipeable Views](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)

you can also download code from this site and also see video in given sit

Comment: you first see given link. i used in my project Perfactly work in my application dear.